# emacs-jupyter result of an org-babel source block displayed as hash

Tags: org-mode, jupyter

When I execute a jupyter source block in org-mode, I get a hash instead of the result

For instance, I get

```
#+begin_src jupyter-python :session sess :async yes
print("haha")
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 0 - c29485e4-fa6a-459d-84a1-cb1aa0c42907
```

emacs tells me the following error:

```
error in process sentinel: json readtable error: 47
```

Does someone know how to get the true result as output ?

emacs v28.2
emacs-jupyter v0.8.2

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it.
I had an old `ob-ipython` and configuration in my init.el and `ob-ipython` was still loaded which seemed to cause the error.